# Как создать выпадающий список в django

Tags: python, html, django

видел такой вариант

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Student(models.Model):

    class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
        JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
        SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
        GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')

    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YearInSchool.choices,
        default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,
    )

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in {
            self.YearInSchool.JUNIOR,
            self.YearInSchool.SENIOR,
        }

###########
# human readable text can then be called by...
Student.YearInSchool.Junior.label

# or from an instance by <instance>.get_<innerclass name>_display() like...
student_inst.get_yearinschool_display()
```

но он мне не очень понятен и хотелось бы, что-то по проще типо `PySimpleGUI.Combo` или что-то в этом духе

Comment: а что хотите сделать?

Comment: @ZaArs  я хотел перенести данный код на сайт https://github.com/Womba306/Test/tree/interfaceOut